# ASP.NET ImageField does not update on AJAX Refresh

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView inside an UpdatePanel  that is hooked up to a DataSource from a database.  One of the fields is configured to display an image (tick or cross).

A Timer runs every 60 seconds and the UpdatePanel is configured to trigger on the Tick event.

It is working in IE, but when the tick occurs, firefox loses the images after the AJAX refresh occrus.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Try passing a random number as querystring with imageurl like 'image.jpg?num=randomnumber' .It may be a caching problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be the bug of FF, Please look at this link [Image inside UpdatePanel not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808916/image-inside-updatepanel-not-working-in-firefox).

Probably you can resolve your issue by this.

Thanks
Arun.